# Where can I find hidden wallpapers on Nexus 7?

Tags: nexus-7, wallpaper

I used to have this picture as Nexus 7's wallpaper, but the desktop restored to a blank wallpaper after I killed the UI process a few weeks ago. I tried to bring back this picture but it was no where in the wallpaper collection. Meanwhile, the gallery does not have this particular picture.

As I searched for this picture on Google, I found there're other people who use it as their Android wallpaper[here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=27541557). Therefore, I suspect that this picture should have come with Nexus 7's pre-built bundle. Moreover, I honestly didn't remember I deliberately downloaded it from somewhere else in the first place.

So, Nexus 7 or other android device owners, could you please check your wallpaper collection and let me know if you find it there? Also, if anyone knows where to obtain it, could you please let me know as well?

Many thanks.

P.S. This is post is totally about my android device and what I'm trying to solve is an issue caused by Nexus 7. Android users are the mostly like group to help, so please don't downvote it for close.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Nexus 7 with stock Jelly Bean 4.2. Wallpapers are stored in /system/app/Launcher2.apk/res/drawable-sw600dp-nodpi as wallpaper_01.jpg to wallpaper_14.jpg but your picture is not here.

I checked wallpapers in version 4.1.1 online here:
https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/jcrom_packages_apps_launcher2/src/bd231599ae9f/res/drawable-sw600dp-nodpi

And your picture is not here too. What Android version do you have?

Comment: Thanks. I was using 4.1 and now upgraded to 4.2. Now that you confirmed, it might be the case that I downloaded this picture somewhere that I just cannot remember. Thank you.

Comment: If you you are using Google's Web History
https://history.google.com/history/?hl=en
and remember approximately the date when you have downloaded the picture, Web History tool may help you to identify the web site where did you find your picture. If you have found that site via Google searching.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually the wallpaper from Golauncher EX. You can download it in the play store.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can find this picture under Golauncher EX? I looked at themes and live wallpapers and there's no way to find it.